# Is there an OnDeserializing/OnDeserialized equivalent for ServiceStack's TypeSerializer?

Tags: datacontractserializer, servicestack

I want to switch some code from using .NET's `DataContractSerializer` to using ServiceStack's `TypeSerializer` for the increased speed benefits.  Unfortunately, the code I inherited relies rather heavily on `OnSerializing`/`OnSerialized`/`OnDeserializing`/`OnDeserialized`, which ServiceStack appears not to call.  Am I missing something?  Assuming not, is there a good way to abuse things to fake out the intended functionality?  `OnSerialized`/`OnDeserialized` can be roughly approximated through reflection, but I'm at a loss for `OnSerializing` and `OnDeserializing`.

Comment: As you're now aware, ServiceStack Text serializers don't call or look for any user-defined event hooks on your models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such facility; you'd have to fork ServiceStack or jacket the serialization/deserialization yourself with appropriate calls.

Comment: This answer is obsolete (as of 2021), see [ServiceStack OnDeserialized Equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66057798/3744182) for how to use ServiceStack's [serialization hooks](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/SerializationHookTests.cs).